# Updating quantity of an item in shopping cart with a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a shopping cart with a table that list all the items you have in it with quantities, price and product name. Now I want users to be able to change the quantity of an item easily. How can I make this work? This solution I made up myself doesn't appear to work:

```
<tr>
        <td><?=$item["product_id"]?></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" id="<?=$item["product_id"]?>">
                <input type="text" name="aantal" value="<?=$item["aantal"]?>">&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" name="change_aantal_<?=$item["product_id"]?>" value="Update">
            </form>
            <?  
                if(isset($_POST["change_aantal_".$item["product_id"].""])) {
                    updateCart($item["id"], $_POST["aantal"]);
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td><?=$item["aantal"] * $item["price"]?></td>
        <td><a href="/removefromcart.php?id=<?=$item["id"]?>">Verwijderen</a></td>
    </tr>
```

The function that actually does the updating works fine. It's just about how I make this form work.

Comment: Did you think about JavaScript or jQuery? Theres the onchange event which triggers when the input changes. You could add the update method in it and your work would be done.

Comment: How can I execute a PHP function on change?

Comment: Oh, you want php ... im sry, didnt notice that. But then i dont know where the actual problem is. Is the function even updateCart() executed? If not, its probably the problem of your if clause, this $_POST there looks extremly strange. And you didnt specify an action in the <form> element. Its valid if you want to sent it to itself, but its not fitting the W3C standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your updateCart() works? 
Remove the product_id from your submit (and also in your if-clause).
Add an hidden input with you $item['product_id'] and call your updateCart() with those values.

So it would be like

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><?= $item["product_id"] ?></td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" id="<?= $item["product_id"] ?>">
            <input type="text" name="aantal" value="<?= $item["aantal"] ?>">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="change_aantal" value="Update">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?= $item['product_id']; ?>">
        </form>
        <?
        if (isset($_POST["change_aantal"])) {
            updateCart($_POST["product_id"], $_POST["aantal"]);
        }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><?= $item["aantal"] * $item["price"] ?></td>
    <td><a href="/removefromcart.php?id=<?= $item["product_id"] ?>">Verwijderen</a></td>
</tr>
```